# Add column with result based on condition checking in SQL select statment

Tags: java, oracle

Is it possible to add column and value on select statement based on some condition. I am trying to add column called status to my result which will display either active or inactive based on the condition check.

I have two columns start date and end date in table. I am sending a date to sql so my select statement should test if this date is between start and end date and set active/inactive text in new column.

I am getting active record with following SQl statement now I want to have inactive status too.

```
select last_name, first_name, 'ACTIVE' as status
from vw_member
where last_name like :lastname
  and   first_name like :firstName
  and TO_DATE(:dateOfCall, 'MM/DD/YYYY') between start_date and end_date
order by last_name, first_name;
```

Comment: You can try something like `Case when 'your test' then 'Active' else 'inactive' end as status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `CASE` statement. An example is described [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php).

```
> select last_name, first_name,  case when TO_DATE(:dateOfCall,
> 'MM/DD/YYYY') between start_date and end_date then 'ACTIVE' else
> 'INACTIVE' end as status from vw_member where last_name like :lastname
> and   first_name like :firstName   order by last_name, first_name;
```